# Access an API Object

Tags: reactjs, json

Please help. I want to get the **NAME** of the campaign stored in an API.
Here is what the JSON looks like:

```json
{
 "campaigns": [
 {
 "links": [],
 "code": "FTTH-FREESETUP-FREEROUTER",
 "name": "FREE setup + router",
 "description": "",
 "category": "fibre",
 "urlSlug": "",
 "isStandardCampaign": false,
 "isDefaultCampaign": true,
 "isPrivateCampaign": false,
         },
         {
             "links": [],
             "code": "FTTH-PREPAID",
             "name": "Prepaid Fibre",
             "description": "",
             "category": "fibre",
             "urlSlug": "prepaid",
             "isStandardCampaign": true,
             "isDefaultCampaign": false,
             "isPrivateCampaign": false,
             "promocodes": [
                 "VUMA-REACH-RECURRING"
             ]
         }
     ],
     "links": []
 }
```

I used `campaigns[0]` and that didn't help.
I tried `campaigns.name` as well but it didn't help.

I am expecting to get the campaign name (it should give me "FREE setup + router" or "fibre")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let data={
    "campaigns": [{
            "links": [],
            "code": "FTTH-FREESETUP-FREEROUTER",
            "name": "FREE setup + router",
            "description": "",
            "category": "fibre",
            "urlSlug": "",
            "isStandardCampaign": false,
            "isDefaultCampaign": true,
            "isPrivateCampaign": false
        },
        {
            "links": [],
            "code": "FTTH-PREPAID",
            "name": "Prepaid Fibre",
            "description": "",
            "category": "fibre",
            "urlSlug": "prepaid",
            "isStandardCampaign": true,
            "isDefaultCampaign": false,
            "isPrivateCampaign": false,
            "promocodes": [
                "VUMA-REACH-RECURRING"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "links": []
};
console.log(data.campaigns[0].name);
```

Is it what you need?

Comment: Would you give me a tick when my solution is good?